# Sapper $Session change not reflected until page reload

Tags: javascript, svelte, sapper

In my nav.svelte component I have:

```
{#if $session.token}
  ${JSON.stringify($session.token)} - ${JSON.stringify($session.token.username)}
{/if}
```

In login.svelte:

```
const { session } = stores();
  let username, password;
  async function onLogin(username, password){
    const response = await fetch(`auth/login`, {
            method:"POST",
            headers:{ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
            body: JSON.stringify({"username":username,"password":password})
    })
    if (response.ok) {
      const json = await response.json();
      session.set({ token: json });
      $session.token = json;
      goto("/");
        } else {
            throw new Error(response);
        }
  }
```

login.js handler:

```
 req.session.token = user; //parsed.token;
        console.log(`req.session.token: ${JSON.stringify(req.session.token)}`);
        res.writeHead(200, {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        });
        res.end(JSON.stringify({ token: user }));
```

server.js:

```
sapper.middleware({
      session: (req, res) => {
        console.log(`% req.session.token: ${JSON.stringify(req.session.token)}`);
        return ({
          token: req.session.token
        })}
      })
```

The output in nav.svelte is:
`${"token":{"_id":"kjbLgeU8k3GPr6jBd8NkCj","username":"matt123","password":"$2b$10$aXMJc64o9W166OL12CG/A.lWyuB9zdPkaNUsze3Lch6Z2khHaTKY.","access":"user"}} - $undefined`

Notice that the data is there, but username outputs undefined.  I believe I am doing something wrong but it is obscure.
Added an issue to the tracker on sapper project:

https://github.com/sveltejs/sapper/issues/1711

Comment: Seems your {$session.token ? $session.token.username : ""} is not reactive and inside the html section. Do you have bind a components var to the store? Plz give a working example to see how you handle the $session.

Comment: Updated some. Is there something special I need to do to make it reactive? (a working example is hard because it's tied to a backend in sapper/mongo). Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps it is a good idea to specify what $session.token should be in comparison? By now it is smthg which is interpreted as boolean. So null, undefind, false become false other values are true (like "").  The first run just announces, that $session.token.username is undefined. So the question might be: When and how is the $session instantiated?

Comment: @nologin Thanks. I updated the question with more details... crazy thing is that JSON.stringify shows data in the token.username, but token.username is null...?

Comment: I guess '${JSON.stringify($session.token.token.username)' will lead to the wanted answer ;). Prove how you set the reference to json.token?